# error: inflate error data error

Tags: perl, unzip

I tried to unzip a password protected zip file using the Perl Archive module.
But endedup with an error

error:

`inflate error data error at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 367.`

Can anyone helps me to find asolution, and unzip a password protected zip file(WINRAR used to zip a file with password).

Please find the code i use:

```
my $file = "D:\\Public\\Sample-Programs\\tempzip\\TESTFILE.zip";
my $password = "aaa";

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($file) or die "can't unzip";
foreach my $member_name ($zip->memberNames) {
    my $member = $zip->memberNamed($member_name);
    next if $member->isDirectory;
    $member->password($password);
    my $contents = $zip->contents($member) or die "error accessing $member_name";
    print("contents = $contents");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks stevieb for updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution on another way and might be I guess its helpful:

Untested for using winzip [refered from](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-win32-users/18391/):

```
my $Prog     = $ENV{"ProgramFiles"}.'\\WinZip\\WINZIP32.exe';
my $Password = 'Secret Password';
my $ZIP      = 'filename.zip';
my $Path     = 'c:\\my\\folder';
system("$Prog -e -s\"$Password\" \"$Zip\" \"$Path\"");
```

Tested for using 7zip:

```
my $file = "test.zip";
my $password = "secret";
my $Prog     = "\"c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zG.exe\"";
system("$Prog e -p$password -y $file");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i dont use winzip i use WINRAR

Comment: thanks ssr i just change the EXE to WINRAR and the 7zip format worked ,thank you so much.